# VBA: Why is my macro getting slower the more sheets it produces?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

As suggested yesterday, I'm splitting my question into two parts, although I think they might be connected:

I have an Excel-macro that basically works, but it gets slower the more sheets are added by the macro.
It creates up to a few hundred sheets and every sheet is a different report, so I have to keep all the sheets.
In the beginning 10 sheets take about 10 seconds, but at around 70/80 sheets the time almost triples.
Is this just because of the number of sheets, or can I speed it up again?

The code is a bit longer so I've reduced it to address the issue and marked it in the code:

```
Sub My_Issues()
    Dim ColumnLetter As String, item As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sheetCount As Integer, TotalRow As Integer, TotalCol As Integer
    Dim uniqueArray As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Get unique brands:
    With Sheets("Brand")
    .Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Sheets("Sales").Columns("R:R").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim uniqueArray(1, 1)
    uniqueArray(1, 1) = .Range("A3")
    Else
    uniqueArray = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value
    End If
    End With

    TotalRow = Sheets("Sales").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    TotalCol = Sheets("Sales").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, TotalCol).Address, "$")(1) 'Num2Char
    sheetCount = 0 'Counter for statusbar

For x = 1 To UBound(uniqueArray, 1)
    item = uniqueArray(x, 1) 'item=Brand
    'Filter sales for each brand:
    With Sheets("Sales")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(TotalRow, TotalCol)).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=item
    End With

    With Sheets("Agents")
    'Delete old...
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Clear
    '...and get new
    Sheets("Sales").Range(Sheets("Sales").Cells(3, 2), Sheets("Sales").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    'List with all agents
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Agents").Range("A2", Worksheets("Agents").Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    With Sheets("Report")
    .Range("I4") = cell 'Copy agent and update the formulas within the report
'->Issue: It takes around 10 seconds to fill 10 sheets with the reports of 10 agents.
'When I reach 70-80 sheets, it slows down to 30 seconds for 10 sheets.
'Is this just because of the number of sheets, or can I speed it up again?

    .Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Report")

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value 'Replace all formulas with values
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell

    sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
    If sheetAnz Mod 10 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = sheetAnz 'Get statusupdate every 10 sheets
    End With
    Next

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'Continue with other stuff.... sorting sheets and so on

Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: I see you're copy-pasting some content from some sheets to another. The key here is - Are there any formulas in those ranges? If you're adding more and more ranges with formulas, since you didn't disable Automatic calculation, it will get slower every time it needs to recalculate.

Comment: I didn't turn it off, cause I need the calculations to update the report for the new agent. After that I replace all formulas with their values with ''ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value''. So I think that's not an issue.